# How to mix PS3- and PC-Sound for one headset?

Tags: pc, ps3, audio-hardware

I like to play games on my PS3 while I'm talking to my mates on Teamspeak on my PC. So I switch to PTT (Push To Talk) on Teamspeak to not broadcast my TV-Sound all the time and simply play. That is kind of annoying, because I need to press some button on a keyboard next to me to speak and may need to pause the game to prevent broadcasting while I'm talking.

Both Screens (TV & Monitor) are not directly next to each other. My Monitor is connected via DVI to my PC, my PS3 videosignal is going through HDMI to my TV and the audiosignal goes through the optical port to my home theatre.

So my question is: Is there a way to mix both audiosignals together (without any audio/video-ansync-lag) on one headset? I think I might need a 2 channel mixer, but I'm not very familiar with those kind of hardware. Maybe there is an easier way to do this?

If you need any further information let me know :)

PS: I don't know if this question is fitting this part of SE :/ If not feel free to point me to the right site. Thanks!

Comment: I feel this doesn't really have anything to do with gaming, I'm afraid.

Comment: A good acid test (am I using the idiom right?) to check whether a question is suitable for Arqade is to take out anything *directly* related to gaming from the question and see if it still makes sense. At its core this is about audio mixing, so it would probably do better on [su].

Comment: I've voted for reopening this question, because I finally found a cheap solution for this and want to share my answer. It can be closed afterwards again. Otherwise I'll edit it into my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend heavily on a variety of factors such as the TV you have already and the features of your PC soundcard;

#### Does your PC have a suitable audio input to run your PS3 through the PC?

If your PC has something more than a standard on board sound card then you might have dedicated digital inputs for audio, if not then you should at the very least have a line in connection which should allow you to run the audio from your TV into your PC.

If yes - you can use the Windows mixer or mixer that accompanies your soundcard in your PC, and plug your headset into your PC and do the mixing there.

#### Does your TV have a suitable audio input to run your PC through the TV with your PS3?

Many TVs will allow you to play multiple audio inputs at once, for example HDMI and the audio inputs  (red and white RCA) from composite video. If yours does - you can plug your headset into your TV, your PC into your TV with a cable that has a standard jack on one end and red/white RCA on the other and adjust the volume levels of TeamSpeak using your PC to get the balance right.

#### Failing that...

You're going to need some kind of hardware solution, whether this is replacing the soundcard in your PC to allow you to relay the audio from your PS3 through the PC or getting something like an external mixer or amplifier of some kind which will require a variety of cables to plug both your PS3 and PC into it.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is: Is there a way to mix both audiosignals together (without any audio/video-ansync-lag) on one headset?

What I do is run a long, 3.5mm audio jack connector from my TV to the headphone port of my TV. I leave the jack unplugged from the TV to hear from the speakers, and plug it in when I need to listen over the headset on the PC (I do this often when streaming video, because if I listen to the stream directly it will be delayed, unlike the audio line-in).

Take the PC end of the audio cable and plug it into either a 3.5mm line in jack or a microphone jack. If you have to plug it into a mic jack you will need to set Windows (I assume Macs allow similar but I'm not sure how) to "listen" to that port instead, do this by going to Sound options in Windows, go to the Recording tab and right click the line in/mic jack that your PS3 is plugged into (if you don't see it, right click the whitespace and enable "show disabled devices", the line might be disabled). Go to properties of the line in/mic and make sure, on the "listen" tab, it's set to "listen to this device".

As a sidenote I've noticed I get some whitenoise when my PC volume is very loud and no signal is coming over the 3.5mm line. You can disable the line in device or just unplug the jack from the PC to stop hearing that.

Note if you have an optical audio cable and an optical in port on your PC you can have your PS3 output to all sound sources (option in the audio settings) and run that line to your PC as well. Might give less whitenoise since it's a better cable (the length of my 3.5mm cable might be why too, it's 15'). Then you'd just mute your TV when using the headset and disable the sound device on the PC when not listening to it.